Does LC circuit convert DC to AC?
I was experimenting with LC circuit (Class 12 - Physics, India) in CircuitJS1 Simmulator.
Interestingly, the LC circuit given below was converting DC into AC.
Circuit:

Circuit Specifications:

DC power source = 311 V
Inductance of the inductor = 1 H
Capacitance of the capacitor = 10.132 µF

The value of the inductance and the capacitance is calculated for resonance with frequency of 50 Hz and both the graph are caculated for the ammeter, voltage in right and current in left.
Observations :

Max voltage = 321 V (Peak) = 226.947 V (RMS)
Max current = 1.022 A (Peak) = 0.722554 A (RMS)
Time Period = 20.155 ms = 0.020155 s
Frequency = 49.6154800298 /s

My question is that, if this circuit actually works like this? If yes, then how it is working, and why we need MOSFETs to convert DC to AC?


I don't believe this question should be closed. While it might need some improvements, it is at its core both valid and answerable.

What's happening here is that your simulator doesn't model losses in the LC resonant circuit that you've built. When you start the simulation, the DC power source's voltage jumps from 0V to 311V once. This action gives a one-time "kick" to the LC resonator, causing it to start oscillating. The energy delivered by this "kick" is limited. However, since losses aren't modeled, the oscillation continues forever in the simulation.
In real life, you can't build a LC resonator without losses, especially if you want to use it for energy conversion. The reason for that is simple: If you connect a load to your resonant circuit, you're taking energy out of it, and this will quickly halt the oscillation when there's no energy left.
If you want to keep the oscillation going beyond the initial turn-on "energy kick", you need to add circuitry that continuously replenishes the energy in the resonator. This is typically done with active circuitry containing transistors (BJTs or MOSFETs).
As for what's actually converting DC to AC in your simulation: It's the act of starting the simulation, which causes the DC voltage to jump from 0V to 311V. That's a very brief one-time pulse of AC voltage being fed into the resonator.
Turn-on without losses:

Turn-on with losses (a load connected to the "AC side"):

I've made the turn-on moment (at t=10ms) more explicit in these simulations. As you can see, the energy in the resonant tank is limited, causing the oscillation to quickly die down when you connect a load.

BDW sir , Which simulation software are you using?

@MrinmoySarkar It’s from LTspice.
